# how to move anchor text up inside of anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the anchor text to move up in the anchor tag. Here's the anchor text that says, "Play":
[image]

I'm trying to get this anchor text that says "play" to move up slightly by putting some padding at the bottom, but that doesn't seem to work when I try to use the p or span elements. I don't know if there is another way to get the text to move up or not, but I could use some help with this.

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>nested anchor links in divs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styling.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="outer-container">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/play logo.webp" alt="play" id="play" height='25px' width='25px'><span>Play</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">




        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: gray;
}

#sidebar a {
    background-color: rgb(20, 15, 15); 
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

span {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar img {
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-right: .1em;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to align the "Play" text in the middle of the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juat add `display: flex; align-items: center;` to `#sidebar a`.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: gray;
}

#sidebar a {
    background-color: rgb(20, 15, 15);
    color: white;
    /* display: block; */
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

span {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar img {
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-right: .1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="outer-container">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <a href="#">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2285/512/1_Youtube_colored_svg-512.png"
                    alt="play" id="play" height='25px'
                    width='25px'>
                <span>Play</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not familiar with all of the display properties yet.@Nitheesh